# How can I simulate a refund of an in app purchase in the sandbox environment?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

My application implements in app purchase of non-renewable and renewable subscriptions. I know I can use https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt to verify the validity of a receipt for one of these subscriptions, but is it possible to simulate the refund of a purchase in the sandbox environment?

If so, how is this done?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Refunds aren't technically possible through Apple.  If your customer contacts Apple for a refund, they'll typically redirect the customer to you to handle this.

If you really want to offer refunds of your products, you'll have to keep a database somewhere of purchases and track which refunds you have given and to whom.

Comment: Apple will sometimes issue refunds, or so I've heard from clients that have apps with subscription purchase.

Comment: You'd lose 30% if you refund directly instead through Apple. Not correct.